# リストから特定の長さのDictへの変換方法

Tags: python, python3

長さが2万を超えるリストがあります．
そのリストから8個ずつ(Keyが1番目の要素，残りの7つがValue)に分けてDictへと変換したいです．（そのリストは8で割り切れます）
具体的な例を出すと，リスト

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27]
```

のようなリストに対して，期待する出力は

> tmp_dict = {1: [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9], 11: [8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27]}

のようになります．要するに８の倍数の値をKey，それ以外の7つをValueに変換するといった内容になります．
どなたかご教授お願いします．
[追記]Keyが重複する可能性があります．重複した場合はそのKeyとValueは無視して元のKeyとValueのままにするような仕様にしたいです．

Comment: 辞書(dict)のキーが重複する事はあるのでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis データはそれぞれ固有というわけではないので，重複することはあり得ます．

Comment: そうなりますと、重複しているキーの値は「上書き」される事になりますが、それは構わないのでしょうか？

Comment: @metropolis それは避けたい事象なのですが，回避する方法などはあるのでしょうか？

Comment: キーが同じ場合はリストを連結してしまう、という対応が考えられます。

Comment: @metropolis つまり期待する出力とは異なる形になるということですか？

Comment: 重複しているキーの場合、Value は `7 * 重複数` の長さのリストになります。

Comment: @metropolis なるほど．つまりKeyが重複していれば期待する出力のような形は得られないということですね．

Comment: はい、ですので、その辺りの仕様を明確にして質問文に追記してみて下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スライスして辞書化する例です。

```
A = [ 1,  3,  5,  2,  4,  6,  7,  9,
     11,  8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27,
     11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]

group_length = 8
dict = {}
for i in range(int(len(A) / group_length)):
    start = i * group_length
    end = (i + 1) * group_length
    key = A[start]
    # 既にキーが存在する場合はスキップ
    if key in dict:
        continue
    dict[key] = A[start + 1: end]

print(dict)
# {1: [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9], 11: [8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27]}
```

Answer (score 1):

### 重複した場合は元の Key : Value 優先タイプ

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27, 11, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 47]
sz = 8
lsk = [A[i] for i in range(0, len(A), sz)]
# lst = [A[i:i+sz] for i in range(0, len(A), sz)]
# tmp_dict = {lst[i][0]:lst[i][1:] for i in range(0, len(lst)) if lst[i][0] not in lsk[:i] }
tmp_dict = {A[i]:A[i+1:i+sz] for i in range(0, len(A), sz) if A[i] not in lsk[:i//sz] }
print(tmp_dict)  # {1: [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9], 11: [8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27]}
```

### 重複した場合は後の Key : Value で上書きするタイプ

```
A = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27, 11, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 47]
sz = 8
tmp_dict = {A[i]:A[i+1:i+sz] for i in range(0, len(A), sz)}
print(tmp_dict)  # 上書き {1: [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9], 11: [28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 47]}
```

### 重複した場合は Value を連結するタイプ

```
def list_to_dict(lst, sz):
    from collections import defaultdict
    lst = [lst[i:i+sz] for i in range(0, len(lst), sz)]
    dic = defaultdict(list)
    for ls in lst:
        dic[ls[0]] += ls[1:]
    return dict(dic)

A = [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27, 11, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 47]
tmp_dict = list_to_dict(A, 8)
print(tmp_dict)   # 連結 {1: [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9], 11: [8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 47]}
```

lst = [lst[i:i+sz] for i in range(0, len(lst), sz)]
は
lst = list(map(list, list(zip(*[iter(A)]*sz))))
と性能比較した方が良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

[more-itertools: More routines for operating on iterables, beyond itertools](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools) に、[unique_everseen](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) というメソッドがあります。

> **more_itertools.unique_everseen(iterable, key=None)**
>
> Yield unique elements, preserving order.

これと、[numpy.array_split()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) を使う方法です。

```py
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
from numpy import array_split

A = [
   1,  3,  5,  2,  4,  6,  7,  9,
  11,  8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27,
   1, 25, 22, 30, 32, 35, 37, 42,
]

tmp_dict = {
  lst[0]: lst[1:].tolist()
  for lst in
  unique_everseen(array_split(A, len(A)//8), key=lambda x: x[0])
}

print(tmp_dict)
=>
{1: [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9], 11: [8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 27]}
```